# Animate Height of Div

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to animate the height of a `div` that wasn't specified a height. I'm using the `max-height` method, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882615/5244870) suggests.

The problem is, first the `div` becomes visible, then the original `div` gets hidden. So you're seeing both `divs` at once. What I want, is the first `div` to get hidden, then have the next div appear, and only then have the height animate.

I would rather use only css, but it seems impossible without. So I'm open to JavaScript solutions.

#### JSFiddle

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab'),
  content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('change', tabChanged);
}

function tabChanged(e) {

}
```

```css
.tabGroup {
  background-color: brown;
  color: yellowgreen;
}
.tabGroup > div {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rad1:checked ~ #tab1,
#rad2:checked ~ #tab2,
#rad3:checked ~ #tab3 {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabGroup">
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab" checked="checked" />
  <label for="rad1">Tab 1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab" />
  <label for="rad2">Tab 2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab" />
  <label for="rad3">Tab 3</label>

  <div id="tab1" class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="content">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="content">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  </div>
</div>
```

Please don't post any JQuery suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protip: be more specific in the question about what it is you want.

Anyways, to get the slide effect in both directions but keeping the "original" height, I merely split the bg from the text, duplicated the text (so I'd have the correct dynamic heights), and animated, using `z-index` to "remember" the previous bg height.

There's probably a better way (that doesn't involve text duplication), but I can't think of it off the top of my head.

Note that this is the best duplicated content method; 2 copies instead of n copies if we were to dupe with "proper" backgrounds.

Also note that this "widget" will take up `510px + menu height` at all times. This is because the height memory and keeping the text inside the bg required removal from document flow for this implementation.

I'd suggest styling the tab buttons as well, so it's clear which tab you're on.

```css
.tabGroup {
    color: yellowgreen;
    overflow:visible;
}

.tabGroup input.tab{
    display:none;
}

.tabGroup > .menu{
    background-color: brown;
}

.tabGroup > .bgs{
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.tabGroup > .bgs > .content {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;

    background-color: brown;
    padding:0;
    max-height: 0px;
    width:100%;

    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    
    color:transparent;
}
.tabGroup > .bgs > .content + .content{ background-color: #57f; }
.tabGroup > .bgs > .content:last-child{ background-color: #5f7; }


.tabGroup > .txts{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    
    padding:5px 0;
    height:500px;/*so its footprint is the max size we allow*/
    width:100%;
    
    overflow:hidden;
    color:transparent;
}
.tabGroup > .txts > .content{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-100%;
    
    padding:5px 1px;
    width:100%;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    
    color:black;
    
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#rad1:checked ~ .txts > .tb1 ~ .content,
#rad2:checked ~ .txts > .tb2 ~ .content,
#rad3:checked ~ .txts > .tb3 ~ .content {
    left:100%;
}


#rad1:checked ~ div > .tb1,
#rad2:checked ~ div > .tb2,
#rad3:checked ~ div > .tb3 {
    max-height: 500px;
    left:0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab" />
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab" />
    <div class="menu">
        <label for="rad1">Tab 1</label>
        <label for="rad2">Tab 2</label>
        <label for="rad3">Tab 3</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bgs">
        <div class="content tb1">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
            software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="content tb2">
            Tab 2 content
        </div>
        <div class="content tb3">
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
            one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
            et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
            1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
            English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="txts">
        <div class="content tb1">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
            software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="content tb2">
            Tab 2 content
        </div>
        <div class="content tb3">
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
            one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
            et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
            1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
            English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### OLD ANSWER

---

Just needed to give the visible one its own transition rule. I set it so it waits 0.5s then transitions its `max-height` for 0.5s.

When you have multiple styles with transitions, the `transition` on the state you're going to is the one that wins (as in, the `transition` poperty transitions instantly and before any other effects are processed).

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab'),
  content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('change', tabChanged);
}

function tabChanged(e) {

}
```

```css
.tabGroup {
  background-color: brown;
  color: yellowgreen;
}
.tabGroup > div {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rad1:checked ~ #tab1,
#rad2:checked ~ #tab2,
#rad3:checked ~ #tab3 {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabGroup">
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab" checked="checked" />
  <label for="rad1">Tab 1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab" />
  <label for="rad2">Tab 2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab" />
  <label for="rad3">Tab 3</label>

  <div id="tab1" class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="content">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="content">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with that is, the height animates to 0, then animates to the designated height. I want it to animate from the current height to the designated height

Comment: @Horay Two issues with that. First, what do you want the text to do- pop immediately to the tab you have open while the height catches up with the old text still visible if the new is smaller & and the height hasn't caught up, or something else? Second, in order to do that the divs are going to have to be on top of eachother (or they'd need to be animating their actual `height` rather than their `max-height`), which means I'll have to remove them from document flow.

Comment: What I really want, is the text to slide to the side. The direction of the slide should depend on if the `selectedRadioIndex > previousSelectedRadioIndex`.

Comment: @Horay Done, though somewhat jankily.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Really appreciate it! The only thing is, if you make tb2 backgroundcolor blue, you will see it when going from tb1 to tb3 or vice versa. How can I make it not show up at all when going from tb1 to tb3? Another issue is, when changing a tab, you can see the previous tab going to a height of 0. How can I make it that you don't see the height changing? I'm now fully open to JavaScript. Thanks again! https://jsfiddle.net/b8L91nwa/

Comment: @Horay The background color switching issue was because I wasn't animating the padding; I've fixed that. As for seeing the text go to 0, that's needed to prevent text from existing outside of the background when switching to a shorter tab. You could avoid that using more content duplication (a fixed third set that generates an `overflow:hidden;` box around `.bg, .txts`), but I was trying to keep things reasonably scalable (and a single dupe isn't that bad). If you wanna switch to JS, I'm not well versed. I would suggest going with [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) if possible, though.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what exactly happens when you click a tab? What are the steps? in the previous JSFiddle I sent you. https://jsfiddle.net/b8L91nwa/